Prevent pnpm creating node_modules inside libs for Nx monorepo
I am working on migrating my Nx Angular monorepo from npm to pnpm.
When using npm, I can simply install the project and get a single root node_modules, and there is nothing inside the libs.
However, after changing to pnpm, the install creates the root node_modules, along with a node_modules inside every buildable lib that has a package.json.
Based on documentation, I have tried the following configuration
.npmrc
link-workspace-packages=true

pnpm-workspace.yaml
packages:
  - 'apps/**'
  - 'libs/**'

example lib package.json
{
  "name": "my-buildable-lib",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/core": "^18.0.0",
    ...
    "@my-org/app/feature": "workspace:*",
    ...
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "sideEffects": false
}

then run pnpm -r install and it should only create the root node_modules directory, but no matter what I try, i end up with a node_modules for every lib.
Is there something I am missing to make this work correctly inside my Nx monorepo?
